# CORS preflight channel did not succeed, already added access-control-allow headers

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cors

I'm getting an error like this in Firefox, when I make an AJAX call to obtain an access token.

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44302/identity/connect/token. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed)**

I setup my CORS configuration to allow almost anything in web.config and I still get this error. Here are my request and response headers.

[image]

Any ideas why it's not going through?

Comment: Make sure you don't hit this, https://blog.lextudio.com/2014/11/how-to-handle-cors-preflight-requests-in-asp-net-mvcweb-api-with-windows-authentication/